# How can I edit footnote style in memoir class when using biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, memoir, chicago-style

I am using the `memoir` class for my theis together with package `biblatex-chicago` for my citations. When I compile my document I get the following warning from `biblatex-chicago`.

> Since you are using the 'memoir' class, I'm leaving the formatting of the foot- and/or end-note mark and text to you.

In a previous document (that was not a memoir document class) my footnotes were showing with superscript numbering in the text and with inline numbering in the footnote as per the preferred method of the Chicago manual of style but in the memoir class they show as superscript in both the text and the footnote.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, bookpages=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
address = {Anytown},
booktitle = {Example book},
pages = {5},
title = {{Any book you want}},
year = {2000}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname} % if you’re using biblatex
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\autocite{book1}

\end{document}
```

I have reviewed the rather large manual for memoir class but I have got rather lost on how to set up the footnote styling. The manual for `biblatex-chicago` make referrence to the warning above but not much else with regard to the memoir class. What I would like to know what do I need to do to set my footnotes to show inline numbering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something like this:

[image: Footnote with period]

Then just modify the style of the `footmark` as described in the memoir manual (235-36):

```
\footmarkstyle{#1.\,}
```

And put it somewhere in the preamble of your document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
  address   = {Anytown},
  booktitle = {Example book},
  pages     = {5},
  title     = {{Any book you want}},
  year      = {2000}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, bookpages=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % you need the file extension here 

\footmarkstyle{#1.\,}
\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\autocite{book1} % the starred version looks better with a footnote

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is so helpful! Chicago likes a period after the number, so `\footmarkstyle{#1.\,}`

Comment: @Andrew Cashner you are right, it should be with a period. I changed my answer accordingly.