# Adjust footnote indentation in memoir

Tags: footnotes, indentation, memoir

Following up to [How can I edit footnote style in memoir class when using biblatex-chicago?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212481/how-can-i-edit-footnote-style-in-memoir-class-when-using-biblatex-chicago)

I have been fixing my footnotes with a hack adjusting `\@makefntext`, but I would rather use `memoir`'s interface.

But I can't figure out how to make the footnote number be indented the same width as the `\parindent` of the body text above.

I include both my attempt at a `memoir` solution and my hack below; you can try both or see the default by moving the `\begin{comment}` and `\end{comment}` lines.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}

\newlength{\myparindent}
\setlength{\myparindent}{2em}
\setlength{\parindent}{\myparindent}


\footmarkstyle{#1.\,}
\newlength{\myfootmarkindent}
\setlength{\myfootmarkindent}{\footmarkwidth}
\addtolength{\myfootmarkindent}{\myparindent}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{\myparindent}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{-\footmarkwidth}
\setlength{\footparindent}{\myparindent}


\begin{comment}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]%
        {\setlength{\parindent}{\myparindent}%
        {\@thefnmark.\,}%
        \setlength{\parindent}{\myparindent} #1}
\makeatother


\end{comment}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]\par\lipsum[3]}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you set the `\footmarkwidth` to zero and add space before the `footmark` everything aligns quite nicely:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\footmarkstyle{\hspace{\parindent}#1.\,}    % indent the footmark 
\setlength{\footmarkwidth} {0em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}   {0em}
\setlength{\footparindent} {\parindent}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]\footnote{\lipsum[2]\par\lipsum[3]}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful and elegant! I'm not sure why this isn't spelled out in the `memoir` manual.