# Specific footnote style in memoir

Tags: footnotes, memoir

I have implemented the following style for my footnotes in memoir

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength\footparindent{1.2\parindent}

\newlength{\foothelp}
\newlength{\foothelpextra}
\footmarkstyle{%
\setlength{\foothelp}{\footparindent}%
\setlength{\foothelpextra}{\widthof{\textsuperscript{#1}}}%
\addtolength{\foothelp}{-\foothelpextra}%
\textsuperscript{#1}\hspace{\foothelp}%
}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]}

\setcounter{footnote}{999}\footnote{\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

But if I change the font size I need to manually adjust the \footparindent. Is there a better way of implementing this style? Moreover, is it possible for the indent in the footnotes to match the indent in the body text? This style is very much like in this question:

[Adjust footnote indentation in memoir](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212514/adjust-footnote-indentation-in-memoir)

The difference is that the footnote mark should be flushleft.

[image]

Edit: Added a picture displaying the style. As can be seen all the indents doesn't quite match up.

Comment: I can't get your MWE to work. I think you have a problem with your code for `\footmarkstyle`.

Comment: @Peter Wilson That's weird. It compiles with no problems on my setup.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\setlength{\footmarkwidth} {0em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}   {0em}
\footmarkstyle{\makebox[\footparindent][l]{\textsuperscript{#1}}}
```

Set `\footparindent` to `\parindent` proper to have them line up.

In this MWE the `\XXX` is just an easy way to show the alignment, it is designed to not disturb.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength\footparindent   {\parindent}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth} {0em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}   {0em}
\footmarkstyle{\makebox[\footparindent][l]{\textsuperscript{#1}}}


\newcommand\XXX{\llap{\smash{\rule[-\paperheight]{0.1pt}{2\paperheight}}}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]}

\setcounter{footnote}{999}\footnote{\XXX\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me by 40 seconds. LOL

Comment: Setting \footmarkwidth and \footmarksep equal to 0 solved the problem. But the \makebox solution is much more elegant than mine and in particular doesn't require additional packages. The solutions are identical, so I don't know what I should do in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{calc}

\footmarkstyle{%
  \makebox[\parindent][l]{\textsuperscript{#1}}%
}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\footmarksep}  {0pt}
\setlength{\footparindent}{\parindent}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]}

\setcounter{footnote}{999}\footnote{\lipsum[1]\lipsum[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image: footnote]